# Xcart 4 - static page content working when added to help menu but not on home page

Tags: x-cart

I have a static page called 'welcome' which just contains text and should display on the home page but doesn't - there's nothing there. However, if I edit the static page and select the 'Show a link to the page in Help menu?:' option, a link to the page appears at the bottom of the site and when I visit that page, the content is displayed.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

[Static pages](https://help.x-cart.com/X-Cart:Static_Pages) are accessible by their own URLs.

To change your welcome page follow the [instructions](https://help.x-cart.com/X-Cart:FAQs#My_store_says_.22This_is_a_demo_store_powered_by_the_X-Cart.22._How_do_I_change_it.3F) (Shortly, it is the template like *skin/common_files/customer/main/welcome.tpl / skin/your_skin/customer/main/welcome.tpl*).